# Managing asynchronicity and performing multiple MySQL queries in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am running into some issues with handling the asynchronous nature of `nodejs`. I am using the `nodejs-mysql` connector to fetch data. In essence, the code below is performing a query to fetch `file_url` and sending the information to myApi.  A second query should be run right after to update database with result returned from the api(`inputId`). However, the previous is not working do to it's asynchronous manner(connection closes before processing everything). What would be the best way to do the below using the `async` module?

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
var async = require("async");
var Q = require('q'),
    myApi = require('myApi')('xxxxx');

//DB
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "root",
    database: "test"
});


//1ST Query - Fetch Urls, then upload file to api
con.query('SELECT file_url, file_id FROM myfiles', function(err, rows) {
    if (err) throw err;
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {

        // File URL for upload
        var fileUrl = rows[i].file_url,
            createInputPromise, createEncodingProfilePromise;
        var fileId = rows[i].file_id;

        // Create myApi Input
        createInputPromise = myApi.input.create(fileUrl);

        //WHERE THE ACTION OCCURS!
        Q.all([createInputPromise, createEncodingProfilePromise]).then(
            function(result) {
                console.log('Successfully uploaded file: ' + result[0].url + ' inputId: ' + result[0].inputId);

                //2ND Query - Save the inputId return by api for each file
                con.query(
                    'UPDATE myfiles SET myApi_input_id = ?  WHERE file_id = ?', [result[0].inputId, fileId],
                    function(err, result) {
                        if (err) throw err;
                        console.log('Changed ' + result.changedRows + ' rows');
                    }
                );

            },
            function(error) {
                console.log('Error while uploading file to api:', error);
            }
        );
    };

});

con.end(function(err) {});
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers posted are great options but I ultimately wanted to get it accomplished with the use of `async`. I came across the [waterfall](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-waterfall) pattern:

> Runs an array of functions in series, each passing their results to
>   the next in the array. However, if any of the functions pass an error
>   to the callback, the next function is not executed and the main
>   callback is immediately called with the error.

I ended implementing the following:

```
var pool = mysql.createPool({...});

function fn(callback) {
    var getConnection = function(callback) {...};

    async.waterfall([
        doQuery.bind(null, getConnection),
        doSomethingAsyncWithResult,
        doUpdate(null, getConnection)
    ], function(err, result) {
        getConnection.end();
        callback(err, result);
    });

}

function doQuery(connection, callback) {
    connection.query(sql, callback);
}

function doSomethingAsyncWithResult(result, callback) {
    ...something...
    callback(null, anotherResult);
}

function doUpdate(connection, result, callback) {
    connection.update(sql, [result], callback);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of this depends on how you are handling these: `createInputPromise`, `createEncodingProfilePromise`. More code in relation to those two would be helpful towards a good answer. And where exactly in the code do you get the issue? Does `console.log('Successfully uploaded file: ' + result[0].url + ' inputId: ' + result[0].inputId);` output to the console, or is there an error before that?

Right now, are you certain that `myApi.input.create(fileUrl)` is returning a promise? You will need to look over the docs for that API to make sure that it is. If not, then you can use the Q library to create one:

```js
var inputPromise = Q.defer();
var encodingProfilePromise = Q.defer();

inputPromise.resolve(myApi.input.create(fileUrl));
encodingProfilePromise.resolve(/*encoding profile code*/);

Q.all([inputPromise.promise, encodingProfilePromise.promise]).then(function(result) {
  /*blah blah blah*/
});
```

With more info I could give a more precise answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of async module, I would look on it in a bit different manner. Lets go with generators.

```
let co = require('co');
let parallel = require('co-parallel');
let sequelize = require('sequelize'); // also read documentation to provide connection details (this is just pseudocode)


let gen = function*() {
  let inputId = yield fetch_file_url(); // this function should be generator or should return promise
  let res = yield sequelize.query(`INSERT INTO... ${inputId} `);
}

co(function*() {
  let files = ['f1', 'f2', 'f3'];
  let gens = files.map(file => gen(file));
  let arrayOrResults = yield parallel(gens, 5);  // 5 threads
    // done
}).catch(function(err) {
  // catch errors
});
```